# Springboot Data JPA 2.4.6 JUnit Test case Failing with Function "TOP" not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2, querydsl

I have the below code in my `SpringBoot(2.4.6)` and `Java 11` project

```
public class EmployeeRepositoryImpl implements CustomEmployeeRepository {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private Querydsl querydsl;

    private QEmployee queryEmployee;

    public EmployeeRepositoryImpl(@Qualifier("tenantEntityManagerFactory") EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
        this.querydsl = new Querydsl(entityManager, (new PathBuilderFactory()).create(Employee.class));
        this.queryEmployee = QEmployee.Employee;
    }


    @Override
    public Page<Employee> getEmployeesWithOrgs(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable, List<UUID> orgIds) {
        JPQLQuery<Employee> query = new JPAQuery<>(entityManager);
        BooleanBuilder whereClause = new BooleanBuilder();

        query.select(queryEmployee).from(queryEmployee);
              
        query.leftJoin(QEmployeeOrganization.EmployeeOrganization)
                .on(QEmployeeOrganization.EmployeeOrganization.Employee.eq(QEmployee.Employee));
        whereClause.or(QEmployeeOrganization.EmployeeOrganization.id.organizationId.in(orgIds));
        whereClause.or(QEmployeeOrganization.EmployeeOrganization.id.organizationId.isNull());
        query.where(whereClause).distinct();
    

        Long totalElements = query.fetchCount();
        List<Employee> result = querydsl.applyPagination(pageable, query).fetch();
        return new PageImpl<>(result, pageable, totalElements);
    }
}


@Test
public void testGetEmployeesWithOrgs() {
    UUID EmployeeGuid1 = UUID.randomUUID();
    UUID EmployeeGuid2 = UUID.randomUUID();
    UUID orgGuid1 = UUID.randomUUID();
    UUID EmployeeGuid3 = UUID.randomUUID();
    UUID orgGuid2 = UUID.randomUUID();
    Employee org1Employee1 = EmployeeBuilder.aEmployee().withVersion(1L).withEmployeeStatus(EmployeeStatus.ACTIVE).withGuid(EmployeeGuid1).withOrganizations(Arrays.asList(orgGuid1)).build();
    EmployeeRepository.save(org1Employee1);
    Employee org1Employee2 = EmployeeBuilder.aEmployee().withVersion(1L).withEmployeeStatus(EmployeeStatus.ACTIVE).withGuid(EmployeeGuid2).withOrganizations(Arrays.asList(orgGuid1)).build();
    EmployeeRepository.save(org1Employee2);
    Employee org2Employee1 = EmployeeBuilder.aEmployee().withVersion(1L).withEmployeeStatus(EmployeeStatus.ACTIVE).withGuid(EmployeeGuid3).withOrganizations(Arrays.asList(orgGuid2)).build();
    EmployeeRepository.save(org2Employee1);

    Page<Employee> latestVersionOfAllEmployees = employeeRepository.getEmployeesWithOrgs(null, PageRequest.of(0, 10), Arrays.asList(orgGuid1));
    Assert.assertNotNull(latestVersionOfAllEmployees);
    Assert.assertEquals(2,latestVersionOfAllEmployees.getContent().size());
}
```

Above code is wokring fine in my application but when I run the test case its failing with below error, seems like the issue is generated Query has `Top` keyword which is not a valid function in `H2(1.4.196)` . If I remove `.distinct()` then the test case is passed. Is this a bug? or is there any workaround for this?

```
2021-09-10 00:55:32.610  WARN [cm,,] 45248 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 90022, SQLState: 90022
2021-09-10 00:55:32.618 ERROR [cm,,] 45248 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Function "TOP" not found; SQL statement:
select distinct TOP(?) employee0_.id as id1_54_, employee0_.CreatedBy as createdb2_54_, employee0_.CreateDT as createdt3_54 from Consent.[employee] employee0_ left outer join Consent.[employeeOrganization] employeeorg1_ on (employeeorg1_.[employeeId]=employee0_.id) where employeeorg1_.[OrganizationId]=? or employeeorg1_.[OrganizationId] is null [90022-196]


org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not prepare statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy198.getLatestVersionOfAllemployees(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.ReflectionMemberAccessor.invoke(ReflectionMemberAccessor.java:45)
    at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.defaultanswers.ForwardsInvocations.answer(ForwardsInvocations.java:48)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl.handle(MockHandlerImpl.java:106)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.NullResultGuardian.handle(NullResultGuardian.java:29)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler.handle(InvocationNotifierHandler.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor$DispatcherDefaultingToRealMethod.interceptAbstract(MockMethodInterceptor.java:157)
    at com.abc.cm.repository.tenant.employeeRepository$MockitoMock$295937979.getLatestVersionOfAllemployees(Unknown Source)
    at com.abc.cm.repository.tenant.employeeRepository$MockitoMock$295937979$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5561eb44.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.abc.cm.repository.tenant.employeeRepository$MockitoMock$295937979$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d0041406.getLatestVersionOfAllemployees(<generated>)
    at com.abc.cm.repository.employeeRepositoryTest.getemployeesWithOrgs(employeeRepositoryTest.java:374)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2103)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2040)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2018)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2849)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2831)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2663)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2658)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1636)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1604)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.getResultList(AbstractJPAQuery.java:160)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.fetch(AbstractJPAQuery.java:202)
    at com.abc.cm.repository.tenant.employeeRepositoryImpl.getLatestVersionOfAllemployees(employeeRepositoryImpl.java:94)
    at com.abc.cm.repository.tenant.employeeRepositoryImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b9cae3bc.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
    at com.abc.cm.repository.tenant.employeeRepositoryImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$db82086e.getLatestVersionOfAllemployees(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:524)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:531)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:156)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 90 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "TOP" not found; SQL statement:
select distinct TOP(?) employee0_.id as id1_54_, employee0_.CreatedBy as createdb2_54_, employee0_.CreateDT as createdt3_54_ from Consent.[employee] employee0_ left outer join Consent.[employeeOrganization] employeeorg1_ on (employeeorg1_.[employeeId]=employee0_.id) where employeeorg1_.[OrganizationId]=? or employeeorg1_.[OrganizationId] is null [90022-196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readJavaFunction(Parser.java:2487)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readFunction(Parser.java:2539)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTerm(Parser.java:2876)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readFactor(Parser.java:2390)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readSum(Parser.java:2377)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readConcat(Parser.java:2347)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readCondition(Parser.java:2178)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readAnd(Parser.java:2150)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readExpression(Parser.java:2142)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleSelectPart(Parser.java:2053)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2085)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1940)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1755)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1743)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:449)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:321)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:293)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:258)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:578)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:519)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1204)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:337)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
    ... 143 more
```

Comment: Did you configure `Querydsl` to use the H2 dialect?

Comment: No, I did not. How do I configure?

Comment: I am wondering whether the TOP(X) expression is introduced by Querydsl or during Hibernates JPQL to SQL conversion. Can you provide the outcome of `query.createQuery().unwrap(Query.class).getQueryString()`?